# HGVS python package : How to parse complex insertions?

Tags: python, variants

In [HGVS](https://github.com/biocommons/hgvs) package, how to create more complex variants ?

I just wonder how can I parse more complex insertions such as those :

`NM_004006.2:c.940_941ins[903_940inv;851_885inv]`

`NC_000006.11:g.8897754_8897755ins[(543);8897743_8897754]`

`NC_000006.11:g.10791926_10791927ins[NC_000004.11:g.106370094_106370420;A[26]]`

(All taken from the [varnomen website](https://varnomen.hgvs.org/recommendations/DNA/variant/insertion/))

When I tried I got parsing errors (mainly because of the brackets that represent the inserted sequences)

Whole traceback :

```py
In [6]: var_g = hp.parse_hgvs_variant('NM_004006.2:c.940_941ins[903_940inv;851_885inv]')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hgvs/parser.py in rule_fxn(s)
    129                 try:
--> 130                     return self._grammar(s).__getattr__(rule_name)()
    131                 except ometa.runtime.ParseError as exc:

~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/parsley.py in invokeRule(*args, **kwargs)
     97                                      [["message", "expected EOF"]], err.trail)
---> 98             raise err
     99         return invokeRule

~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py in _or(self, fns)
    597                 m = self.input
--> 598                 ret, err = f()
    599                 errors.append(err)

/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py in _G_or_212()
    803                 self._trace('| dna_in', (5502, 5510), self.input.position)
--> 804                 _G_apply_213, lastError = self._apply(self.rule_dna_ins, "dna_ins", [])
    805                 self.considerError(lastError, None)

~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py in _apply(self, rule, ruleName, args)
    494                 memoRec = self.input.setMemo(ruleName,
--> 495                                          [rule(), self.input])
    496             except ParseError as e:

/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py in rule_dna_ins(self)
    980                 return (_G_many1_275, self.currentError)
--> 981             _G_consumedby_276, lastError = self.consumedby(_G_consumedby_272)
    982             self.considerError(lastError, 'dna_ins')

~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py in consumedby(self, expr)
    675         oldInput = self.input
--> 676         _, e = expr()
    677         slice = oldInput.data[oldInput.position:self.input.position]

/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py in _G_consumedby_272()
    977                     return (_G_apply_274, self.currentError)
--> 978                 _G_many1_275, lastError = self.many(_G_many1_273, _G_many1_273())
    979                 self.considerError(lastError, None)

/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py in _G_many1_273()
    974                     self._trace('<dn', (5909, 5912), self.input.position)
--> 975                     _G_apply_274, lastError = self._apply(self.rule_dna, "dna", [])
    976                     self.considerError(lastError, None)

~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py in _apply(self, rule, ruleName, args)
    494                 memoRec = self.input.setMemo(ruleName,
--> 495                                          [rule(), self.input])
    496             except ParseError as e:

/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py in rule_dna(self)
   2667             self._trace('= dna_iupa', (11894, 11904), self.input.position)
-> 2668             _G_apply_809, lastError = self._apply(self.rule_dna_iupac, "dna_iupac", [])
   2669             self.considerError(lastError, 'dna')

~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py in _apply(self, rule, ruleName, args)
    494                 memoRec = self.input.setMemo(ruleName,
--> 495                                          [rule(), self.input])
    496             except ParseError as e:

/pymeta_generated_code/pymeta_grammar__Grammar.py in rule_dna_iupac(self)
   2682                 return (_G_python_813, self.currentError)
-> 2683             _G_pred_814, lastError = self.pred(_G_pred_811)
   2684             self.considerError(lastError, 'dna_iupac')

~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ometa/runtime.py in pred(self, expr)
    648         if not val:
--> 649             raise e
    650         else:

ParseError: 
NM_004006.2:c.940_941ins[903_940inv;851_885inv]
                        ^
Parse error at line 1, column 24: Syntax error. trail: [dna_iupac dna dna_ins dna_edit c_posedit c_variant hgvs_variant]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

HGVSParseError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9d483e266162> in <module>
----> 1 var_g = hp.parse_hgvs_variant('NM_004006.2:c.940_941ins[903_940inv;851_885inv]')

~/playground/python/hgvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hgvs/parser.py in rule_fxn(s)
    130                     return self._grammar(s).__getattr__(rule_name)()
    131                 except ometa.runtime.ParseError as exc:
--> 132                     raise HGVSParseError("{s}: char {exc.position}: {reason}".format(
    133                         s=s, exc=exc, reason=exc.formatReason()))
    134 

HGVSParseError: NM_004006.2:c.940_941ins[903_940inv;851_885inv]: char 24: Syntax error
```